# REST API for Whiskerboard

Tags: api, rest, status

I need some help with implementing a status board with a REST API. I've already found the two best options (in my opinion): Stashboard and Whiskerboard.

I have already tried Whiskerboard and I find it easy to install and deploy because it does not need Google App Engine's SDK to be used locally. However, I need something like Stashboard's REST API: http://readthedocs.org/docs/stashboard/en/latest/restapi.html

I know that Whiskerboard is based on Stashboard so probably they have the same REST API. But I cannot seem to find any documentation on Whiskerboard's REST API. Moreover, I looked into each status board's models and there are lots of differences, with Whiskerboard's being largely simpler compared with that of Stashboard's, so they must not have the same REST API.

I will appreciate it if anyone can provide me a link to Whiskerboard's REST API which should be much like Stashboard's. If there really is none, some other solutions could still be suggested. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't have the same REST API.  You could find this out by reading the code. If you want a similar REST API you have the following options:

1. Code the feature yourself.
2. Ask the developer of Whiskerboard for the feature.
3. Ask someone else at your organization to code and contribute the feature.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this solution forked by sijis and myself, jvasallo, that we have been working on. He forked the repo for whiskerboard and added an API to it. Still uses Django, and recently I did some work porting it to 1.5.1. Initially, Whiskerboard is a 1.3 Django app.

https://github.com/sijis/whiskerboard